# Android ExpandedListView get group position

Tags: android

I have an `ExpandedListView` with a group which contains a label and button.

In the `getGroupView` method of the `ExpandedListAdapter`, I set up the button to accept a click on the Button

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder viewHolder;
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.editButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

viewHolder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               long pos = ListAdapter.this.listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
               Timber.i("Position "+pos);
            }
}
else {
  viewHolder = (ChatViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

}
```

Within the `onClick` method, how do I find out what is the currently selected group row? The call to the listView's `getSelectedItemPostion` in the Button onClick returns -1. The `groupPosition` variable is 0 because the `ViewHolder` is always the same `ViewHolder` created when the `convertView` was initialised.

I have tried using on `OnGroupClickListener` which correctly works out the row but it is triggered only when I click the label and not when I click on the button.

```
this.listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new   ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            Timber.i("GroupPosition "+groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I guess having a viewHolder for each group row rather than sharing the viewHolder for all group rows might be answer but it seems a heavyweight solution.

How else can you find out what the current group row is?

James

Answer (score 0):

`ExpandableListView` uses something called a *packed position* to go between the flat list and the hierarchical list.

I don't think `ExpandableListView` has a concept of selecting a group (see `ExpandableListAdapter.isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)`.  I think you can only select a child.  But let's see what the code says:

```
        viewHolder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               long packedPos = ListAdapter.this.listView.getSelectedPosition();
               if (packedPos != ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_VALUE_NULL) {
                   int groupPos, childPos;
                   int packedPosType = ListAdapter.this.listView.getPackedPositionType(packedPos);
                   switch (packedPosType) {
                   case ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_NULL:
                       Timber.i("packed position type was null ???");
                       break;
                   case ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP:
                       groupPos = ListAdapter.this.listView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPos);
                       Timber.i("groupPosition "+ groupPos);
                       break;
                   case ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD:
                       groupPos = ListAdapter.this.listView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPos);
                       childPos = ListAdapter.this.listView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPos);
                       Timber.i("groupPosition "+ groupPos + ", childPosition " + childPos);
                       break;
                   }
               } else {
                   Timber.i("no selection");
               }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I only added the final so that I could print out the groupPosition in the onClick method

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.  See my updated answer.  I typed the code in directly, so I don't even know if it will compile without errors.  But that should get you started.